# What are some applications of gerrymandering for Electronic Design Automation/Very large-scale integration?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, combinatorial-design

There are many algorithms used for Very large-scale integration design (VLSI) or EDA (Electronic Design Automation). Most of them are challenges that imply some combinatorial/mathematical optimization.

For instance, some well-known problems and their algorithms can be interesting for the field - Graph generation, Floorplanning, Global or Cell placement, Routing, etc. - because they model problems natural of VLSI or EDA, although the problems are not originally circuit-design related.

I wonder if Gerrymandering can have any application for VLSI or EDA.